# Catch c++ native addon cout/console messages in electron.js or node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, native-module, node-addon-api

C++ native module's std::cout console message don't get printed on console once module gets build.

Is there any way to print runtime std::cout messages on console AND then we can catch those messages in electron app using node.js

How does node.js runs native module, does it run it on the same thread as a sandboxed program or on a different thread?.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout` console messages do get printed to the console in Node.js for sure - I don't know for electron.js.
Both the module initialization and the initial entry when called from JavaScript happen in the main V8 thread. There is no sandboxing at all.